# How do I set up gluster in a simple non-clustered configuration?

Tags: server

I would like to set up [glusterfs](http://www.gluster.org/) to replace my use of NFS4, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(inprogress answer, any help testing this and editing would be appreciated, this works and has been tested on 12.04, but only by me!)*

This is a step by step tutorial based on Michael J. Chudobiak's [guide](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.fedoraproject.org/msg40298.html) for Fedora. This assumes that you're trying to share the `/fileserver` directory from a central server to clients. I could never get this work in the past but gave it a shot in 12.04 and is now actually easier to me than using NFS.

#### On the server:

Install the server: `sudo apt-get install glusterfs-server`

First create a volume you want to share, you can name it whatever you want, in this example I'm naming it `volumename`, and then you use your server's DNS name, I don't have DNS for my machines at home so I user servername.local to use the avahi-assigned DNS name:

```
sudo gluster volume create volumename transport tcp yourservername:/fileserver
```

Now we start the volume:

```
sudo gluster volume start volumename
```

And that's it! The server is now serving a gluster share called `volumename`.

#### On each client:

Install the client: `sudo apt-get install glusterfs-client`

Now let's mount the shared glusterfs volume

```
    mount -t glusterfs yourservername:/volumename /mountdirectory
```

On the client, see if you can access the files in `/fileserver`. If
not, read the `/var/log/glusterfs/*` files on both the client and the server.

To mount the share at boot, you can add this to your `/etc/fstab`

```
yourservername:/volumename /mountdirectory glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

References:

- Mailing list post on [migration to glusterfs](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.fedoraproject.org/msg40298.html)
- http://www.howtoforge.com/distributed-storage-across-four-storage-nodes-with-glusterfs-3.2.x-on-ubuntu-11.10 (This article is quite good)